# iOS: Adding a subview to an object's view from a UIColor category?

Tags: ios, objective-c, object, subview, objective-c-category

Okay so this question might sound a bit confusing, and I'm sure many of you are going to question what I'm trying to do instead of providing an answer, so please just try to answer or provide a suggestion.

I have a `UIColor` category where an object (let's say `loginButton`) can call a method in this category (i.e. `+ (UIColor *)colorWithAwesomeness`). I've returned a color and everything is fine. The problem is one of the steps requires me to add a subview to the object's view. How can I access that object from within this method. I've tried `self` (which obviously doesn't work bc `self` in this case is `UIColor` if I set this method as an instance method), and I've also tried `[self class]` which refers to this category class.

Is there a way to do this so that I can set the color and add a subview all by calling one line in my mainController:

```
self.loginButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithAwesomeness];
```

P.S. I'm sure I can subclass this object, but I would love to be able to do it the way I mentioned above, because I would love it to be applicable to any NSObject with a color property.

Comment: To modify an object from a `UIColor` category, to me, seems like a bad design strategy. Subclassing is the better option.

Comment: I agree with you. I just have several colorWith methods and it would be cool to do the same with gradients, except those require adding a CAGradientLayer to an object's view. I was thinking of setting the backgroundColor to say red, and then apply a gradient layer above from red to orange.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused a little by what exactly you are asking. But if I am reading it right you just want to have a reference to the original object which called your category method, so you can do something fancy with it.. Can't you just pass the object as a parameter in the method call?

```
self.loginButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithAwesomenessAndObject:(id)someObject];
```

I may have gotten confused and missed the point, but I hope this helps

Comment: This may work. Once I pass the object (assuming I'm passing: self.loginButton), how can I retrieve it's view so that I can add a subView to it.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I think UIButton is a subclass of UIView. So if you have the button do you not automatically have the view?